# Send Large Data with WCF without Streaming

Tags: c#, wcf

We are trying to build a web service that can send/receive large data files from kb~gb sizes.

I know that we should use streaming to preform that so is not going to crash the memory.

But problem is we don't want to change our design, or more like, now we are going to try to see what will happen when we transfers large file say just 150mb file in a byte[] buffered transfers mode with WCF. (I know is goign to buffer the whole file into memory... and crash/exception if we transfer gb size files...)

But even so, they want to see what happen, so I have my wsHttpBinding in WCF config:

```
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true"/>
      <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="524288"/>
  </system.web>
....

  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="wsHttpBinding1" closeTimeout="00:10:00" openTimeout="00:10:00"
          receiveTimeout="00:30:00" sendTimeout="00:30:00" bypassProxyOnLocal="false"
          hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"                  
                                    maxBufferPoolSize="52428800" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536000"
          messageEncoding="Mtom" useDefaultWebProxy="true">
      <security mode="None" />
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
```

Then my client app config:

```
          <wsHttpBinding>
                <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IPrintService" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
                      openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:30:00" sendTimeout="00:30:00"
                      bypassProxyOnLocal="false" transactionFlow="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                                    maxBufferPoolSize="52428800" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536000"
                      messageEncoding="Mtom" textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true"                           
                      allowCookies="false">
                      <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                            maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                      <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00"
                            enabled="false" />
                  <security mode="None"/>
                </binding>
          </wsHttpBinding>
```

When I transfers small data it works fine, but when I try to transfers 150mb file, it gives me exceptions:

> InnerException = {"Unable to write data to the transport
>   connection: An operation on a socket could not be performed because
>   the system lacked sufficient buffer space or because a queue was
>   full."}

I tried to increase maxReceivedMessage and such, but it still having the same problem....

======

Edit: I tried to increase all possible value above to... 2147483647....  I can sent a 30mb file successfully..but still not 150mb.... And I also tried to use this CustomBinding:

```
<customBinding>         
        <binding name="LargeCustomBinding" 
                 receiveTimeout="01:00:00"  
                 openTimeout="01:00:00"  
                 closeTimeout="01:00:00"  
                 sendTimeout="01:00:00"> 
          <binaryMessageEncoding  
            maxReadPoolSize="2147483647"  
            maxSessionSize="2147483647"  
            maxWritePoolSize="2147483647"> 
            <readerQuotas  
              maxArrayLength="2147483647"  
              maxDepth="2147483647"  
              maxBytesPerRead="2147483647"  
              maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"  
              maxStringContentLength="2147483647" /> 
          </binaryMessageEncoding> 
          <httpTransport  
            maxBufferSize="2147483647"  
            maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"  
            maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647"/> 
        </binding> 
      </customBinding>
```

But I am still getting the same problem....

=========

Edit 2: I guess I should put concern on how I sending the data, maybe I was wrong, I have an Object MyData:

```
    byte[] LargeData = File.ReadAllBytes(this.LargeDataPath.Text);
    MyData.LargeData = new List<KeyValuePair<string, byte[]>>()
    {
        new KeyValuePair<string, byte[]>("DATA", LargeData)
    };

    myServiceClient.SendDataAsync( new SendDataRequest(MyData));
```

There should be no problem? All I did is just sending one big byte[] inside a list.....

Comment: Try this: `maxStringContentLength="2147483646" maxArrayLength="2147483646"`

Comment: The problem may be here: `maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384"`

Comment: Are you hosting via IIS? It may have a max. content size enforced. Can't remember where to check this...

Comment: @Dour High Arch: No, is not hosting via IIS. This is happen in Visual Studio 2010 and I used WCF Service Library to create the service.

Comment: Just wonder: did you solve the problem here?

Comment: @larosalv Kovtunenko nope, still have no idea what went wrong. (But this thing is from last year lol)

Comment: @KingChan and I still wonder what is wrong :)

Answer (score 5):

You should be sending a smaller chunks of data with a separate send method calls.

Put the data you want to send into a byte array.
Then realize the logic on both ends, that will know how to handle sizes and just start sending the data in a smaller pieces, one by one. When you have sent an entire file, it will get concatenated into an array on a client and you will be able to do further processing.

Comment: Yes, we did come out with this method, but they want to see what will happen for doing this first.

Comment: King, I didn't understand you completely of your comment, though I am 100% sure that you should not try to send a large array of data in one service package. Any network problem would break your transfer for good. With "small pieces" method you have the ability to resend a part of data, in case network goes silent for a short period of time, given that the connection is recoverable of cause.

Comment: So what they want me to do is just experiment, through I know for sure about those problem will occurs.  I can foreseek the problem you have mention, and someone in the team alraedy wrote a example code of transfering with chunk of data.  But They will cause the design to be change (and we don't have much time left).  So the manager want to just try out transfers byte[] for now.... Even through I told him the problem you were telling me.

Answer (score 3):

Fix this first:

```
maxStringContentLength="8192"
maxArrayLength="16384"
```

And ensure you have

```
maxStringContentLength="2147483646"
maxArrayLength="2147483646"
```

On both client and server.

I was sending 30Mb over WCF without problems.

And check out [this](http://forums.silverlight.net/post/435515.aspx)

Comment: strange... I tried your fix and as well used the CustomBinding in link you have provided and I am still getting the same error...  I did update the bind on the WCF config, then update my cilent config....strange...

Comment: @king strange indeed. the exception points to `maxBufferPoolSize="52428800"`, which is only 62Mbs. But if you ruled this out, I have little idea what is wrong.

Comment: @king I'd suggest to triage the problem by sending files of increasing size (with 1Mb step) to get where it breaks. As soon as you done, you get which constant from config messes it up.

Comment: hmm 123mb was fine, but until 130mb it dead...Currently I am trying with the CustomBinding above...